# Blank space at bottom of page (messy code?)

Tags: html, css

my code is all jumbled up I believe. I have a ton of white space down at the bottom of my page and I don't know why. I've basically just been going with whatever works thus far but I also want my page to be responsive and it scales really weird atm. This is probably a really hard question to help with but if anyone can I would be super grateful. Any suggestions on what to do are extremely appreciated.

Heres the code:

http://jsbin.com/rugidepebe/1/edit?html,css,output

HTML

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title>Application</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="standard.css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    </head>

    <body>


        <div id="margin-right">
        </div>

        <div id="margin-left">
        </div>


        <div id="navbar">
        </div>

        <div id="contenthead">
        <h1 id="AppHead">Application</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="appbike">
        <h2>Walk/Bike</h2>
        <img src="images/bike.png" id="bike"/>
        </div>

        <div id="appmotor">
            <h2>Motor</h2>
            <img src="images/car.png" id="car"/>
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
body {

margin: 0px;

}

#navbar {

 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: #0C4564;
 z-index: 3;

 }

#margin-right {

position: absolute;
height: 150%;
width: 7.8125%;
background-color: #6FE3C2;
right: 0;
z-index: 1;

}

#margin-left {

position: absolute;
height: 150%;
width: 7.8125%;
background-color: #6FE3C2;
z-index: 2;

}

#AppHead {

text-align: center;
text-decoration: underline;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 3.5em;
font-weight: 600;
color: #575757;

}

#contenthead {
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}


#appbike {

position: relative;
width: 15%;
height: 500px;
background-color: #53A78F;
text-align: center;
margin-left: 25%;
margin-top: 5%;

}

#bike {

width: 70%;
position: relative;
margin-top: 50%;

}

#appmotor {

position: relative;
bottom: 10;
float: right;
width: 15%;
height: 500px;
background-color: #53A78F;
bottom: 498px;
margin-right: 25%;

}

h2 {
 text-align: center;
text-decoration: underline;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
font-size: 2 em;

}

#car {

width: 70%;
position: relative;
margin-top: 50%;
text-align: center;
margin-left: 15%;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have to treat the hmtl & body as wrappers sometimes, you're setting the height to 150%, of which it's parent height is auto so it is a bit confused. Just change your first rule to the following:

```
body, html {
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
```

Adding in height 100% should fix your issue, also added in padding:0; and the html doc to the css selector.

Comment: Thanks! That was way quicker than I thought, you're awesome!